# Map Private Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net5

I have an Asp.Net project with Entity Framework 7 an i have a Email class with a list of attachments.

I don't want to leave that anyone add a item to my list, them i have

`private List<Attachment> Resources { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }`

Now, I want to map to database the relationship with the property Resources instead Attachments.

Entity Framework 7 rise an Exception...

How i can do this.

Comment: Can you tell us what exception EF is throwing?

Comment: Also, why do you want the EF mapping to be done to the `Resources` property instead of the `Attachments` one?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the this to two different model, one internal that maps to the database and another one that's available to users.
It's also the correct way of passing data between layers.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Itay.

Maybe this code example could help you.

Make entities that map to db tables.

```
public class EmailState
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public List<AttachmentState> Resources { get; set; }

    public static Email ToEmail(EmailState state)
    {
        return new Email(state);
    }
}

public class AttachmentState
{
    public static Attachment ToAttachment(AttachmentState state)
    {
        return new Attachment(state);
    }

    public Attachment ToAttachment()
    {
        return new Attachment(this);
    }
}
```

Make classes that are available to users

```
public class Email
{
    public Email()
    {
        this.State = new EmailState();
    }

    internal Email(EmailState state)
    {
        this.State = state;
    }

    internal EmailState State { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments()
    {
        return this.State.Resources.Select(x => x.ToAttachment());
    }

    public void AddAttachment(Attachment attachment)
    {
        this.State.Resources.Add(attachment.State);
    }      
}

public class Attachment
{
    public Attachment()
    {
        this.State = new AttachmentState();
    }

    internal Attachment(AttachmentState state)
    {
        this.State = state;
    }

    internal AttachmentState State { get; set; }
}
```

Define DbContext

```
public class EmailDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EmailState> Emails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AttachmentState> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

Make repository

```
public interface IEmailRepository
{
    void Add(Email email);

    Email GetById(int emailId);
}

public class EmailRepository : IEmailRepository
{
    private EmailDbContext _context;

    public EmailRepository(EmailDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(Email email)
    {
        _context.Emails.Add(email.State);
    }

    public Email GetById(int emailId)
    {
        EmailState emailState = _context.Emails.Single(x => x.Id == emailId);

        return new Email(emailState);
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
using (var context = new EmailDbContext())
{
    IEmailRepository repository = new EmailRepository(context);

    var email = new Email();

    repository.Add(email);

    context.SaveChanges();

    var emailFoundById = repository.GetById(email.Id);
}
```